# AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'now'

Tags: python

Using these lines of code:

```
from datetime import date

date_start = date.now()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'now'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use

```
 import datetime

 now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Or if you are using django 1.4+ and have timezone enabled you should use

```
 django.utils.timezone.now()
```

Comment: django.utils.timezone.now() still give me 2013-03-15 00:00:00 just the date

Comment: Where should I put ' django.utils.timezone.now()' ?  @Prometheus

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```py
import datetime

datetime.date.today()
```

Comment: That doesn't give the current time, only the date.